# Mutator method not changing TextBox text to parameter contents

Tags: c#

I have a series of mutator methods in another class, each of which is linked to a textBox.

(ClassA). Now, I am using an object of ClassA (myClassAObject.setFirstName(param here), to set the text, so the contents of that parameter will display in that textbox.

The content of that mutator method is as follows:

```
public void setFirstName (string newFirstName)
{
txtBoxFirstName.Text = newFirstName;
}
```

I know that the mutator works correctly, because otherwise I'd not see the first name of the patient, I'd see "null", or in the case of a println, a blank space.

**The question is below this line**

The mutator method, for some reason is not causing the textBox to display the text it is given in a parameter, when I access it from the other class. The textBox remains blank. How can I get it to work correctly? I have used MessageBoxes to check if there is a value for the textBox to display, and yes, the contents of the variable appear onscreen.

Here is how the parameter is passed from the second class, to the class in which the textBox resides:

```
myClassAObject.setFirstName(firstName);
```

The code above is example code, but it illustrates what I am doing.

Below is the actual code.

Firstly, from the class where the textBox resides.

Secondly, where the new parameter is being passed from.

```
public void setPatientFirstName(string newPatientFirstName)
    {
        txtBoxPatientFirstName.Text = newPatientFirstName;
    }
Second part of code:

patientRecordClassOverseer.setPatientFirstName(patReaderFirstName);
```

I am using a "Reader" (OleDB) to read the data from the database. It is working, as I have MessageBoxes setup for debugging purposes.

Comment: You need to show a bit more code. Likely you are calling the method on some random instance of form rather than one that is actually shown.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov Alright then. What do you need to see?

Comment: Step through the code in the debugger to see what is happening. If `patientRecordClassOverseer` is actually instance of form currently shown than your code would set text of `TextBox`. I suspect that your newed up way to many "oversser" classes - consider putting breakpoint in the constructor of "overseer" form and see how many times it is called.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov patientRecordClassOverseer is indeed an instance of the Patient Record Class. I declared it as follows in the "reader" method: patientRecordClassOverseer = new PatientRecord(); If I declare it in the constructor, it causes the application to hang, as I am then trying to generate another Patient Record form, which I don't want.

Comment: I thought that somehow "overseer" related to UI... totally lost now. You need to show sample that is *small* and *complete* before anyone can answer your question.

Comment: OK then. "patientRecordClassOverseer" is simply an object of type "PatientRecord" that I use to access the methods contained in PatientRecord.cs, otherwise, I cannot interact with this class when I am working in another. For example: patientRecordClassOverseer.setPatientFirstName(patReaderFirstName);